# Flask app context and celery integration

Tags: python, flask, celery

When integrating celery with a Flask app does celery need to be aware of the Flask application context?

Can I just do something like:

```
import celery from Celery

celery = Celery()

@task
def mytask():
```

Or do I have to do this:

```
def make_celery(app=None):
    app = app or create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
    celery = Celery(__name__, broker=app.config.CELERY_BROKER_URL)
    celery.conf.update(app.conf)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

And then run celery = make_celery(app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celery tasks only need to be aware of the application context if you're doing things that requires it (database queries, etc). Otherwise you can just use Celery as is.

Comment: In cases where the context is needed can I just do `with app.context():  my_task.delay()`  and be ok?

Comment: No. The app context has to be available within the task. That's what `make_celery()` does in your question.